# Solr: Random sort order after index version change

Tags: sorting, random, solr

I am using "`solr.RandomSortField`" to sort search result randomly base on passed random seed. it is working fine and giving same order for same random seed key.

**Issue is:**

When index version get changed by creating/deleting doc using API at run time. Then random order also get changed for same  key between newer and older version.

By Searching in google, i came to know that "RandomSortField" use index version so when index version get changed sort order also get change.

Is there any way to exclude index version from random sort or pass index version to my query to search in older version instead of new updated version and get same order while paging search result.

Mostly getting issue in pagination whenever order change. get duplicate result after some page.

Comment: I do not quite understand your requirement. You use solr.RandomSortField to get a sort order you depend on? This is not quite the intention of it...

Comment: Hi Uwe, I am showing solr search result in random order using "solr.RandomSortField".  I want this random order remain same during single search by any user until he finish all result pagination. It may change in second term search.  while result page navigation it should not change. But index is updating by live data so random order get change during pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `(int)top.getVersion();`?

Using RandomSortField is a module/plugin found here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_5_4_1/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.java

It's useful to be able to have random results that can be persisted for pagination.  But if you have an index that gets updated often, then you will lose your random sort order because of the dependency on the index version. To get around this, you can remove the line i wrote above, or you can even simply:

`return fieldName.hashCode();`

in the getseed function.

you will need to make that into your own custom plugin, like a jarfile or whatever you want, and load that in the same namespace instead.

Comment: From where to remove it ?  Please explain . I don't have solr source .. is i need it?

Comment: @PiyushAghera you can find it here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_5_4_1/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.java and you can make your own custom module that removes the dependence on index version by removing what i wrote in my post. load that custom module instead of the one linked ^^

Comment: @user3610279 I am also wondering how to load a custom module.

Comment: In my tests, this solution is incompatible with Solr Cloud because the random numbers are different across instances.