# RandomSortField not given same result Apache Solr 5.5

Tags: apache, solr

I have Apache Solr 5.5 working. On environments other then live randomSortField is working fine because no reindexing is happening or version is not changing but on live data starts changing even on same random string.

for example:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&fl=name&sort=random_1234%20desc
```

hitting this twice wont give me same result on live environment.

i have checked this [Solr: Random sort order after index version change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126396/solr-random-sort-order-after-index-version-change)
but cant find this file on my solr instance

Comment: Changing that file requires recompiling Solr from source. Are you using a cloud setup with multiple nodes or a single node server? Are there commits happening between the requests?

Comment: i have multiple node servers . Users keep changing the data which cause solr to reindex.  I have pagination implemented which is causing issue data starts to repeat.

Comment: any other solution you can suggest for random sorting in solr?

Comment: did it works for you locally with SolrCloud?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this functionality always behaves unexpectedly with SolrCloud, even when overriding with a custom implementation of this functionality. I suspect this is because of differing `timestamp` values of the same documents across instances / shards / replicas.