# Solr Determinative Random on Solr Cloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We want randomized results that stay consistent with paging. We attempted to modify the solr.RandomSortFieldType by changing the randomSeed function, based upon this stack overflow question: [Solr: Random sort order after index version change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126396/solr-random-sort-order-after-index-version-change).

It modified this function, by removing "(int)top.getVersion()":

```
private static int getSeed(String fieldName, LeafReaderContext context) {
    final DirectoryReader top = (DirectoryReader) ReaderUtil.getTopLevelContext(context).reader();
    // calling getVersion() on a segment will currently give you a null pointer exception, so
    // we use the top-level reader.

    return fieldName.hashCode() + context.docBase + [Removed (int)top.getVersion()];
}
```

Since this did not yield the expected results, I am wondering if it would be possible to do something a little more determinative by creating a stored field that is a hash of the document title field called (title_hash). Then I could replace the getSeed function as follows:

```
private static int getSeed(String fieldName, LeafReaderContext context) {
    final DirectoryReader top = (DirectoryReader) ReaderUtil.getTopLevelContext(context).reader();
    // calling getVersion() on a segment will currently give you a null pointer exception, so
    // we use the top-level reader.

    return fieldName.hashCode() + getTitleHashValue();
}
```

Is it possible to reference a document field value from this function that inside a class that inherits from field type? If so, how would I do that, as I am not familiar with the internals of Solr?